# CS50 credit problem why should mastercard number be invalid

Tags: c, cs50, credit-card, mastercard

I'm trying to code the credit problem for CS50 and it is working for most numbers, but when I run the check I am getting an error saying that my code is returning Mastercard for 5555 5555 5555 4444 and it should be invalid.  Figuring it out manually, I can't see why that card would be invalid.  Double every second digit: 10 (1) + 10 (1) + 10 (1) + 10 (1) + 10 (1) + 10 (1) + 8 + 8 = 22.  Then 22 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 4 + 4 = 50.  50 is a multiple of 10 and the number is 16 digits long and starts with 55 so why is that not a Mastercard?

I'm embarrassed to post my code because I know it is very cumbersome and there are definitely faster, more elegant ways to do the same thing, but this is my first stab at programming so I had to do it the only way that seemed logical in my brain - and I only know the scripts that have been shown in class.

Anyway, here it is, please don't laugh, lol!

```
// To determine if a user's credit card number is valid and which company it belongs to

#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
// To get user input of credit card number
    long card;
    do
    {
        card = get_long("What is your credit card number: ");
    }
    while (card < 0);
// To divide number into digits
    int a = card % 10;
    int b = card % 100 - a; 
    int bb = b / 10;
    int c = card % 1000 - b - a; 
    int cc = c / 100;
    int d = card % 10000 - c - b - a; 
    int dd = d / 1000;
    int e = card % 100000 - d - c - b - a; 
    int ee = e / 10000;
    int f = card % 1000000 - e - d - c - b - a; 
    int ff = f / 100000;
    int g = card % 10000000 - f - e - d - c - b - a; 
    int gg = g / 1000000;
    int h = card % 100000000 - g - f - e - d - c - b - a; 
    int hh = h / 10000000;
    int i = card % 1000000000 - h - g - f - e - d - c - b - a; 
    int ii = i / 100000000;
    int j = card % 10000000000 - i - h - g - f - e - d - c - b - a; 
    int jj = j / 1000000000;
    int k = card % 100000000000 - j - i - h - g - f - e - d - c - b - a; 
    int kk = k / 10000000000;
    int l = card % 1000000000000 - k - j - i - h - g - f - e - d - c - b - a; 
    int ll = l / 100000000000;
    int m = card % 10000000000000 - l - k - j - i - h - g - f - e - d - c - b - a; 
    int mm = m / 1000000000000;
    int n = card % 100000000000000 - m - l - k - j - i - h - g - f - e - d - c - b - a; 
    int nn = n / 10000000000000;
    int o = card % 1000000000000000 - n - m - l - k - j - i - h - g - f - e - d - c - b - a; 
    int oo = o / 100000000000000;
    int p = card % 10000000000000000 - o - n - m - l - k - j - i - h - g - f - e - d - c - b - a; 
    int pp = p / 1000000000000000;

// To multiply each digit and reduce to one digit
    int aaa = a * 2;
    if (aaa > 9)
    {
        int ab = aaa % 10; 
        int ac = aaa % 100 - ab; 
        int ad = ac / 10;
        aaa = ad + ab;
    }
    int bbb = bb * 2;
    if (bbb > 9)
    {
        int ba = bbb % 10; 
        int bc = bbb % 100 - ba; 
        int bd = bc / 10;
        bbb = bd + ba;
    }
    int ccc = cc * 2;
    if (ccc > 9)
    {
        int cb = ccc % 10; 
        int ca = ccc % 100 - cb; 
        int cd = ca / 10;
        ccc = cd + cb;
    }
    int ddd = dd * 2;
    if (ddd > 9)
    {
        int db = ddd % 10; 
        int dc = ddd % 100 - db; 
        int da = dc / 10;
        ddd = da + db;
    }
    int eee = ee * 2;
    if (eee > 9)
    {
        int eb = eee % 10;
        int ec = eee % 100 - eb; 
        int ed = ec / 10;
        eee = ed + eb;
    }
    int fff = ff * 2;
    if (fff > 9)
    {
        int fb = fff % 10; 
        int fc = fff % 100 - fb; 
        int fd = fc / 10;
        fff = fd + fb;
    }
    int ggg = gg * 2;
    if (ggg > 9)
    {
        int gb = ggg % 10; 
        int gc = ggg % 100 - gb; 
        int gd = gc / 10;
        ggg = gd + gb;
    }
    int hhh = hh * 2;
    if (hhh > 9)
    {
        int hb = hhh % 10; 
        int hc = hhh % 100 - hb; 
        int hd = hc / 10;
        hhh = hd + hb;
    }
    int iii = ii * 2;
    if (iii > 9)
    {
        int ib = iii % 10; 
        int ic = iii % 100 - ib; 
        int id = ic / 10;
        iii = id + ib;
    }
    int jjj = jj * 2;
    if (jjj > 9)
    {
        int jb = jjj % 10; 
        int jc = jjj % 100 - jb; 
        int jd = jc / 10;
        jjj = jd + jb;
    }
    int kkk = kk * 2;
    if (kkk > 9)
    {
        int kb = kkk % 10; 
        int kc = kkk % 100 - kb; 
        int kd = kc / 10;
        kkk = kd + kb;
    }
    int lll = ll * 2;
    if (lll > 9)
    {
        int lb = lll % 10; 
        int lc = lll % 100 - lb; 
        int ld = lc / 10;
        lll = ld + lb;
    }
    int mmm = mm * 2;
    if (mmm > 9)
    {
        int mb = mmm % 10; 
        int mc = mmm % 100 - mb; 
        int md = mc / 10;
        mmm = md + mb;
    }
    int nnn = nn * 2;
    if (nnn > 9)
    {
        int nb = nnn % 10; 
        int nc = nnn % 100 - nb; 
        int nd = nc / 10;
        nnn = nd + nb;
    }
    int ooo = oo * 2;
    if (ooo > 9)
    {
        int ob = ooo % 10; 
        int oc = ooo % 100 - ob; 
        int od = oc / 10;
        ooo = od + ob;
    }
    int ppp = pp * 2;
    if (ppp > 9)
    {
        int pb = ppp % 10; 
        int pc = ppp % 100 - pb; 
        int pd = pc / 10;
        ppp = pd + pb;
    }
// To determine if card is valid

    int pra = bbb + ddd + fff + hhh + jjj + lll + nnn + ppp;
    int prb = pra + aaa + ccc + eee + ggg + iii + kkk + mmm + ooo;
// To determine if card is AMEX
    if (card >= 370000000000000 && card < 380000000000000)
    {
        printf("AMEX\n");
    }
    else if (card >= 340000000000000 && card < 350000000000000)
    {
       printf("AMEX\n");
    }
// To determine if card is MASTERCARD
    else if (card >= 5100000000000000 && card < 5500000000000000)
    {
       printf("MASTERCARD\n");
    }
// To determine if card is VISA
    else if (card >= 4000000000000 && card < 5000000000000)
    {
       printf("VISA\n");
    }
    else if (card >= 4000000000000000 && card < 5000000000000000)
    {
       printf("VISA\n");
    }
// To determine if card is INVALID
    else
    {
        printf("INVALID\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: The card number seems to be valid. You likely have an error in your code. Please update the question with your code to get help.

Comment: It is a valid mastercard but it is not `else if (card >= 5100000000000000 && card < 5500000000000000)`

Comment: Thank you so much!  You are right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you are playing with single integers a lot, and code becomes super long and not maintainable. This is quite a bad design.

Instead of integer, use `string` for storing credit card number. To reach the individual numbers in the credit car number, you can just use

```
card = get_string("What is your credit card number: ");

card[i]
```

`i` is the index of credit card number. Starting from zero, you can reach all the numbers in a loop and do calculations.

Comment: This sounds really helpful!!  Thank you - I had no clue how to get individual numbers.  Can you just explain a little more about what the code would look like for each number.  For example, to work with the 5th digit would it be string[i(5)] or string[i5] or string[i]5?  Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry that I made a mistake in the code. string[i] will be card[i]. card is array. Arrays starts from 0. So card[0] = first element, card[1] = second element, .. 5th digit is located at card[4] according to the code snippet in my answer. `i` is just a representation of index (i.e location of elements in array).